# Parsing webpages to extract contents

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, web-crawler

I want to design a crawler, using java, that crawls a webpage and extract certain contents of the page. How should I do this? I am new and I need guidance to start designing crawlers.

For example, I want to access the content "red is my favorite color"  from a webpage which is embedded something like below:

< div >***red is my favorite color***< / div >

Comment: .... just get each page and store it as text? I am so sorry, your question makes no sense.

Comment: I mean more like only pulling certain contents....like common web crawlers  pick up urls from a source website using href attribute. Similary, I am interested in pulling other contents like may be a reviewer's content. Makes sense??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested readings

Static pages:

- [java.net.URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) and [java.net.HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)
- [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) - HTML parser and content manipulation library

Mind you, many of the pages will create content dynamically using JavaScript *after loading*. For such a case, the 'static page' approach won't help, you will need to search for tools in the "Web  automation" category.
[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is such a toolset. You can command you browser to open and navigate pages using a common browser, you may even be able to use a 'headless browser' (no UI) using the [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).

Good luck, there's lots of reading and coding ahead of you.

[edited for examples]

This technique is called **Web scraping** - use it with google for examples. The following are offered as an example of results in my searches, I offer no warranties or endorsements for them

For "static Webpage scrapping" - here's [an example using jsoup](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/web-page-scraping-with-jsoup.html)

For "dynamic pages" - here's an [example using Selenium](http://scraping.pro/how-to-use-selenium-webdriver-with-java/)

Comment: Thank you...the link you have shared seems useful, lot of useful methods...I am going to try them. I found out pulling certain contents from a webpage is quite common like pulling review comments from TripAdvisor, is there any sample available?? I do not find any...it will become easy for me to at least start.

Comment: @user2720919 "is there any sample available??" I've updated my post with some examples I found on the net - see towards the end of the answer. "Thank you...the link you have shared seems useful, lot of useful methods..." usually, thanks are expressed by upvoting the answer and, *if fully answers your question*, accepting the answer (just hover over the number/arrows on the left in the upper side of the answer, I'm sure you'll get the idea)