# Get links from google front page search results

Tags: java, php, curl, domxpath

What im trying to do is get the link to the "View more details" link in the googles knoweldge graph. Its an ad. I have tried using googles api and searching through that but get no results that way. The google link is https://www.google.com/search?q=034000245246, Ive tried XDOM to just scrape with no luck, Ive tried googles api with no luck, im lost with no way to approach this problem. All help is appriciated thanks

Comment: It's likely not possible. Google uses a lot of techniques to block scraping, and prevent automated use.

Comment: The "Jackpot" (google sidebar spot) is in the HTML (not loaded via js after the fact).  Why didn't XDOM work?

Comment: Here's a good explanation of basic how-to techniques: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40120080/1967021

Comment: XDOM didn't work because when I try to get contents from that url it retrieves nothing, works perfect with other links just not that one, I read something about google doing redirects at the beginning which would be fixed by using the "follow link" but then a captcha problem occurs. I've been doing lots of reading and still dont understand how some have managed to scrape it